# Accessing and adjusting height of div in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm currently writing a new theme for my website and I am running into problems dynamically adjusting the heights of div elements in an iframe. The source in the iframe is on my domain, but I can't edit it directly.

What I want to do, is have a script that will read the height of the iframe (for example 1000px), read the height of two divs within the iframe (example #content height=200px and #question height =600px). It then adjusts these two heights to fit the iframe page.

so I guess something that will look like this:

```
var height = $('iframe').height();
var content_height = $('iframe').contents().find('#content').height();
var question_height =  $('iframe').contents().find('#question').height();
var diff = height - content_height - question_height
if diff > 0
   "new content height" = content_height + diff/2
    "new question height" = content_question + diff/2
end
```

I am a complete noob when it comes to javascript, so any help would be great.

Comment: give the iframe and divs an id.. and use yourid.height() ...

Comment: You are using jQuery? Then you can do it, it's just selectors and the `height()` method. Try it!

Comment: I will give it a go just now. Thanks for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 $('iframe').height();
 $('iframe').contents().find('#content').height();
 $('iframe').contents().find('#question').height();
```

Comment: In this case, can 'iframe' be the idea of any iframe on the page? Would I need to do something like this...

Comment: if you have more iframe than you can use id for specific one

Comment: How would I write the part after the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

See rajesh's answer.

For the if statement: don't forget the brackets (and also all the semicolons).

```
if (diff > 0)
```